# How to call SCons global function from a helper-script called by a SConscript?

Tags: python, scons

I have some non-trivial logic necessary to compute the paths to certain source & header file directories and since it applies to multiple SConscripts I put it in a separate .py file, imported from each SConscript that needs it. Now I need to be able to call a SCons global function (in this case, the `Glob` function) from within the helper-script. Previously that function was callable directly from within the SConscripts, but now that I need to call it from the separate helper-script I can't figure out how to call it. I suppose this is probably trivial but I'm really not very familiar with Python.

**UPDATE:**
It seems the ability to call `Glob()` as a "global function" has something to do with some trickery that SCons is playing. Here's an excerpt from the main entry file (SConscript.py, which is not the same as the SConscripts that we pepper all over our source tree):

```
_DefaultEnvironmentProxy = None

def get_DefaultEnvironmentProxy():
    global _DefaultEnvironmentProxy
    if not _DefaultEnvironmentProxy:
        default_env = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()
        _DefaultEnvironmentProxy = SCons.Environment.NoSubstitutionProxy(default_env)
    return _DefaultEnvironmentProxy

class DefaultEnvironmentCall(object):
    """A class that implements "global function" calls of
    Environment methods by fetching the specified method from the
    DefaultEnvironment's class.  Note that this uses an intermediate
    proxy class instead of calling the DefaultEnvironment method
    directly so that the proxy can override the subst() method and
    thereby prevent expansion of construction variables (since from
    the user's point of view this was called as a global function,
    with no associated construction environment)."""
    def __init__(self, method_name, subst=0):
        self.method_name = method_name
        if subst:
            self.factory = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment
        else:
            self.factory = get_DefaultEnvironmentProxy
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        env = self.factory()
        method = getattr(env, self.method_name)
        return method(*args, **kw)


def BuildDefaultGlobals():
    """
    Create a dictionary containing all the default globals for
    SConstruct and SConscript files.
    """

    global GlobalDict
    if GlobalDict is None:
        GlobalDict = {}

        import SCons.Script #     <-------This is referring to a directory with a file named __init__.py, which I've learned is something special in Python
        d = SCons.Script.__dict__
        def not_a_module(m, d=d, mtype=type(SCons.Script)):
             return not isinstance(d[m], mtype)
        for m in filter(not_a_module, dir(SCons.Script)):
             GlobalDict[m] = d[m]

    return GlobalDict.copy()
```

So I thought perhaps I need to `import SCons.Script` in my helper-script:

```
import SCons.Script
```

Unfortunately I still get this:

```
NameError: name 'Glob' is not defined:
  File "D:\Git\......\SConstruct", line 412:
    SConscript(theSconscript, duplicate=0)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 671:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 608:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  .
  .
  .
  File "D:\Git\........\SConscript", line 433:
  .
  .
  .
  File "D:\Git\............\PathSelector.py", line 78:
    src_files.extend(Glob((os.path.join(src_path_a, '*.c')), strings=1))
```

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the helper script, and the Glob function definition. The details matter. How are you importing that function? We will care about the PYTHONPATH env var (it should contain `.` dot for current-working-directory), and we'll care about `os.getcwd()`. If you have a stacktrace, perhaps from a failed `import`, put the full trace into your question. When tracking down import errors, you may find that `$ python -m site` offers helpful diagnostic output.

Comment: @J_H Thanks for offering to help; does my update above provide enough information?

Comment: Hmm, that's a lot of single stepping, not sure what to make of it. Sometimes `l` (list),  `p variable`, `b break_line`, and `c` (continue) are good for concisely skipping a dozen "boring" lines of code that are known to work well. // Feel free to call the builtin [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) directly if you don't need the shim. Now, let's try to focus this question in a way that lets SO participants help out, using a standard template: I typed _a command_, I saw _this_, I hoped to see _that_.

Comment: SCons does some tricks to remove boiler plate where possible but AFAIK even if `Glob` looks like a global function, under the hood SCons still calls it on the default environment object. There is not much point in trying to reproduce those tricks in your *.py file. Just pass the environment to it. I could probably tell more if you provided your code and error you're getting. It would be much more helpful than snippets from SCons' sources.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa How do I pass the SCons environment to my helper-script code? Sorry maybe this is obvious to a Python programmer but I'm not too familiar with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage:

> Global functions may be called from custom Python modules that you import into an SConscript file by adding the following import to the Python module:

```py
from SCons.Script import *
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for reading the manual for me. *-me with my red face-*

Comment: Don't worry about it...it's a BIG manpage.